# UNIX SA venturing into the world of Windows

Tags: powershell, vbscript, scripting

I need to parse a CSV (well, more a tab delimited file) and create a new file that contains unique field - i.e.
RC100  1st line
RC100  2nd line
RC100  3rd line
RC200  1st line

and have in the new resultant file
RC100  1rd line
RC200  1st line

I was going to attempt this using VBScript then wondered if I can accomplish this using powershell (sort with -unique) but obviously didn't acheive success.

Please point me to the right direction.

Thanks.

Ray

Comment: The answer is yes, it can be done with powershell. If you give examples of the input and desired output lines, we can point you in the direction of the correct cmdlets to investigate.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your post has a number of formatting and content typos that are muddling what you are trying to achieve.  For example, your first and second examples are formatted exactly the same when I attempt to edit your post.  Minor typos like "1rd line" are also ambiguous enough to confuse potential solutions.  Help us to help you by cleaning that up. :)

Comment: You could use ``Import-Csv 'your.csv' -Delimiter "`n" | sort -Unique field``. For a more definitive answer you need to provide more information about the content of the files and the desired results. Examples might be helpful.

Comment: Of course the delimiter was supposed to be ``"`t"``, not ``"`n"``. *\*slaps self\**